# How to perform wildcard search on a concat column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets Say i have First Name, Last Name 
now i concat First Name, Last Name like below

```
SELECT CONVERT (nvarchar(50), first_name) + ' ' + CONVERT (nvarchar(50), last_name) AS full_name from usertable
```

now i want to perform a % Wildcard search over full_name like below

```
SELECT CONVERT (nvarchar(50), first_name) + ' ' + CONVERT (nvarchar(50), last_name) AS full_name from usertable Where full_name like 'hos%'
```

is it possible?
by the way i don't want to create a view for this!

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it like below.

```
SELECT CONVERT (nvarchar(50), first_name) + ' ' + CONVERT (nvarchar(50), last_name) AS full_name 
from usertable 
Where (CONVERT (nvarchar(50), first_name) + ' ' + CONVERT (nvarchar(50), last_name)) like 'hos%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing such concatenation operations is to use ISNULL function something like this

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(nvarchar(50), first_name) + ' ', '') 
             +  ISNULL(CONVERT(nvarchar(50), last_name),'')
WHERE ISNULL(CONVERT(nvarchar(50), first_name) + ' ', '') 
             +  ISNULL(CONVERT(nvarchar(50), last_name),'') LIKE 'hos%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use a subquery:

```
select ut.*
from (SELECT CONVERT (nvarchar(50), first_name) + ' ' + CONVERT (nvarchar(50), last_name) AS full_name
      from usertable
     ) ut
Where full_name like N'hos%';
```

This is helpful, because you don't have to repeat the expression in two places -- which can cause maintenance problems.

However, the way that you are looking for the full name, it looks like you only care about the first name.  So this would also work:

```
SELECT CONVERT (nvarchar(50), first_name) + ' ' + CONVERT (nvarchar(50), last_name) AS full_name
from usertable
where first_name like N'hos%'
```

Note that I also changed the constant to be explicitly in the national character set, because you are converting the columns to `nvarchar()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the full name FROM a subquery and use the comparison operator 'Like' afterwards:

```
 SELECT full_name
    FROM(SELECT * 
    ,CONVERT (nvarchar(50), first_name) + ' ' + CONVERT (nvarchar(50), last_name) AS full_name from usertable)t1
    WHERE full_name like 'hos%'
```

Comment: it got This "[Err] 42S22 - [SQL Server]Invalid column name 'full_name'.
"